# Issue in retrieving disk space post deleting records of Postgres DB, even after running VACUUM on database

Tags: postgresql, vacuum

My Postgres db was utilizing ~305 gb of space due to data of last 2-3 years, I went ahead and deleted last 2 year data and ran VACUUM, current used disk space is also ~305 gb even after VACUUM has successfully completed.

Comment: `VACUUM` normally does not reduce the disk space. Try `VACUUM (FULL)`.

Comment: This is the expected behavior.  You should read the docs for the commands you are using  as the first resort, not the last resort.